# python: overriding an imported class to extend functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running some code below:

```
import tweepy
# https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys['consumer_key'], keys['consumer_secret'])
auth.set_access_token(keys['access_token'], keys['access_token_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)
.
.
tweets = api.statuses_lookup(id_batch)
```

i want to extend the functionality of tweepy via my code (rather than wait for tweepy github to to be updated with the same functionality) and add an extra argument to the last line (tweet_mode = 'extended')

I was looking into override two particular functions of a certain class in tweepy. The new functions would be exactly the same as the original except for an additional variable

i created a new customtweepy.py and inside (and i just added the tweet_mode stuff):

```
from tweepy import *


def statuses_lookup(self, id_, include_entities=None,
                trim_user=None, map_=None, tweet_mode=None):
from tweepy.utils import list_to_csv
return self._statuses_lookup(list_to_csv(id_), include_entities,
                             trim_user, map_, tweet_mode)


@property
def _statuses_lookup(self):
""" :reference: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup
    :allowed_param:'id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map', 'tweet_mode'
"""
from tweepy.binder import bind_api
return bind_api(
    api=self,
    path='/statuses/lookup.json',
    payload_type='status', payload_list=True,
    allowed_param=['id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map', 'tweet_mode'],
    require_auth=True
)
```

i want customtweepy to act exactly like tweepy does except when i call:

```
tweets = api.statuses_lookup(id_batch, tweet_mode='extended')
```

it will use the function from my customtweepy instead

but when i replace tweepy and just import customtweepy:

```
import customtweepy
# https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

auth = customtweepy.OAuthHandler(keys['consumer_key'], keys['consumer_secret'])
auth.set_access_token(keys['access_token'], keys['access_token_secret'])
api = customtweepy.API(auth)
.
.
tweets = api.statuses_lookup(id_batch, tweet_mode='extended')
#added extra argument
```

i get the below error:

```
tweets = api.statuses_lookup(id_batch, tweet_mode='extended')
TypeError: statuses_lookup() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tweet_mode'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit API class and add you methods to it.
Adopt following pseudo-code to achieve desired output:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.binder import bind_api
from tweepy.utils import list_to_csv


class ModifiedApi(tweepy.API):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def statuses_lookup(self, id_, include_entities=None, trim_user=None, map_=None, tweet_mode=None):
        return self._statuses_lookup(
            list_to_csv(id_),
            include_entities,
            trim_user,
            map_,
            tweet_mode
        )

    @property
    def _statuses_lookup(self):
        # maybe params needed to be scpecified
        return bind_api(
            api=self,
            path='/statuses/lookup.json',
            payload_type='status',
            payload_list=True,
            allowed_param=['id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map', 'tweet_mode'],
            require_auth=True
        )
```

**main module:**

```
import tweepy
import customtweepy
# https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys['consumer_key'], keys['consumer_secret'])
auth.set_access_token(keys['access_token'], keys['access_token_secret'])
api = customtweepy.ModifiedAPI(auth)
.
.
tweets = api.statuses_lookup(id_batch)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the class component impacts the code. would this mean i would need to import customtweepy.ModifiedApi or something and lose the rest of the tweepy functionality?

Comment: You won't lose other functionality, because class is inherited from tweepy.API. Every method of tweepy.API is remained unchanged except overridden `statuses_lookup` and `_statuses_lookup`

Comment: @user3120554 if you need an example of how class inheritance work - i could provide it in my answer. But, i think, it would be better for you read this [tutotrial](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/)

Comment: after replacing import tweepy with import customtweepy (and replacing tweepy with customtweepy everywhere) i get an error: AttributeError: module 'customtweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'
(i'm guessing from the first line in my code)

Comment: from `customtweepy` you need to import only `ModifiedApi`

Comment: Your argument to `super`, should be the name of the inheriting class, ModifiedApi, rather than the inherited class, tweepy.API

Comment: @StuartBuckingham in Python 3.x: you can just say `super().__init__()` instead of `super(ModifiedApi, self).__init__()`

Comment: I tried: import tweepy......
from tweepy import * ......
from tweepy.binder import bind_api.......
from tweepy.utils import list_to_csv.......


class API(tweepy.API):...... (and then define the two functions without init)
and it seems to work!! for some reason i need both the lines because i will get an error if i exclude one?

Comment: does it make sense to have two imports like this? i now have 4 different imports

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov. Absolutely! Your previous answer had the old style super call though.

Comment: @user3120554 i would suggest you avoid wildcard imports. And it would be better to import required objects to main module directly ( readability matters )

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov without it i keep getting the error: AttributeError: module 'customtweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'

Comment: @user3120554 in main module: `import tweepy` and `from customtweepy import ModifiedAPI`.

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov I've tried that too before, the problem is tweepy has some authentication functionality which fails if i use one line for customtweepy and the rest for tweepy

Comment: @user3120554 strange and hardly to believe. But if so - optimize imports in `customtweepy` and use only it